# Eclipse tasks from specific files

Tags: eclipse, ide, filter, task

In Eclipse (Galileo) is it possible to filter the list of TODO and FIXME tasks by a specific  file, or several files? Instead of having the whole list for the entire project.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can select through the upper right arrow of the Task View the option "Configure Content"

From there, you should select a narrower filter like:

"On selected element only"

[image]

---

[Steve Chambers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1063716/steve-chambers) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004074/eclipse-tasks-from-specific-files/3004188?noredirect=1#comment31772214_3004188):

> To get this to work in **Kepler** (Eclipse 4.3), I had to tick the checkbox on the "`TODOs`" configuration in the top left (rather than "Show all items", which is ticked by default).

Comment: To get this to work in Kepler, I had to tick the checkbox on the "TODOs" configuration in the top left (rather than "Show all items", which is ticked by default).

Comment: @SteveChambers Interesting. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 2):

I am not running Galileo, but slightly older version of Eclipse. However, you can at least filter the task list by task description, if not the file name. Open the menu of the Tasks view and from there choose <s>`Configure Filters...`</s> `Configure Contents...`. From there, you can set up a filter that filters data based on the content of task description. Perhaps you can use this to achieve what you want.

(Plus I'm sure that in case new functionality has been added to the filter configuration in Galileo, it will be obvious from the Configure Contents window.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's called "Configure Contents..." in Galileo.

Answer (score 2):

A better approach for your problem would likely be to chose "On working set" from that dialog, "Select...". Then create a working set, it will ask you what files are part of the working set and only display tasks from those files.

I use this to exclude the "vendors" directory in Symfony2, and the "Zend" directory in Zend Framework, which are full of TODOs and errors that pollute these views.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't see a way to do exactly what you wanted.

In a single file you can open the file and locate the TODO items by the icons in the margin.

You can also open the Tasks view (Window->Show View->Tasks) and sort the tasks by clicking on the column headings. Sorting by "Resource" or "Path" might give you some part of the functionality that you are looking for.

You might also look at the Mylin task management plugin. You can create Mylin tasks from TODO items, and you might be able to to more with Mylin's Task List view than you can with TODO's Tasks view.